# Calculus 1: Optimization Word Problem - Right Triangle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

**Find the maximal area of a right triangle with hypotenuse of length 6.**

I've labeled my triangle with Z being the hypotenuse and the two sides X and Y.

I know 
$$A = BH/2 = XY/2$$

Using the Pythagorean theorem I find that

$$ Y = \sqrt{36-X^2}$$

I then get

$$A = \frac{X\sqrt{36-X^2}}{2}$$

I'm getting the derivative of

$$A'=\frac{-X^2 + 18} {\sqrt{36-X^2}}$$

After setting this equal to 0 to solve for X, i'm getting

$$X^2 = -18$$

Which would give an imaginary number and is incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the area is given by
$$
A(x) = \frac{x\sqrt{36-x^2}}{2}
$$
but derivative is from the product rule:
$$
A'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{36-x^2}}{2} + \frac{x \times (-2x)}{2 \times 2\sqrt{36-x^2}}
      = \frac{18-x^2}{\sqrt{36-x^2}}
$$
So $A'(x) = 0$ if and only if $18=x^2$ or $x = \pm \sqrt{18} = \pm 3\sqrt{2}$, of which you obviously only need the positive one.

Comment: You forgot the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood you are right but it is irrelevant for finding the derivative :) but now it is fixed

Comment: Ah so I was doing the derivative incorrectly. Thanks so much for the help! Also, wasn't sure how to type correctly to make my equations show formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

$$A'(x) = \frac{18 - x^2}{\sqrt{36 - x^2}} $$

$$\frac{18 - x^2}{\sqrt{36 - x^2}} = 0 \Rightarrow \: x_1 = 3\sqrt{2} ,\: x_2 = -3\sqrt{2}$$

$$X = 3\sqrt{2} \:\:\:\:\:\:(=\sqrt{18})$$